# How do you add a class on webform submission in the modal?

Tags: 8, theming, webforms

I am using webform in a modal. now I want to add a class in the confirmation pop up of the webform.
How I add class in submission form in twig. I am using html.html.twig of my theme to show webform in pop up. in below code I want a class {{ webform_submisson}} if webform get submitted in the same pop. As I am single modal for webform and confirmation

```
 <div class="modal fade ticket-system-form {{ webform_submisson}}" id="TicketSystemInformation" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="TicketSystemInformationLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">   
  <div class="modal-header d-block">
    <a class="ticket-system-logo" href="/" title="Home" rel="home">
      <img src="/sites/default/files/logo-header%5B1%5D.png" alt="Home">
    </a>
<h4 class='modal-heading w-100'>dfgdfgfg</h4>
    <h5 class="modal-title w-100" id="ContactInformationLabel"></h5>
   
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    {{ drupal_entity('webform', 'ticket_system') }}           
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you place the button that opens the modal? Add the class to the modal directly. You can add a class to the data-dialog-options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53828339

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with js below is my code: Hope it will help to other

```
(function ($, Drupal, drupalSettings) {
  Drupal.behaviors.customPacificadvisors = {
    attach: function (context) {
      var webform = jQuery(context).closest('form.webform-submission-form');
      if (webform.hasClass("webform-submission-ticket-system-form")) {
        var form_confirmation_obj = webform.find('.webform-confirmation');
        if (form_confirmation_obj.length > 0) {
          jQuery("#TicketSystemInformation").addClass("webform-submision-class")
        }
      }
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal, drupalSettings);
```